# Is there a quick way to generate a <%@Register...%> line for a user control?

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, user-controls

- I make a user control and then want to include it on a page
- I have to always manually type the @Register line at the top of my .aspx file, e.g.

  <%@ Register TagPrefix="edward" TagName="GetQuote" src="~/Controls/GetQuote.ascx"  %>
- Is there any way to automatically create these @Register lines?

(I tried dragging in the .ascx file from the Solution Explorer, doesn't work.)

**Problem solved**: I was dragging into my source view instead of design view. Thanks DilbertDave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't get this issue - are you dragging to the aspx in source or design mode?

Dragging in Design mode creates the Register line for me.

Answer (score 1):

try adding your control to the toolbox (via Tools > Choose Toolbox Items) and then dragging it onto your page from the toolbox? (your controls would need to be in a separate dll)